# Writing an exception function

Tags: function, exception, higher-order-functions

I am currently learning on an online learning platform, and my code has to pass the test cases(included below)
**Heres the question:**

Write a higher-order function exception_function which will return a function with exceptions. exception_function should take in a function f(x), an integer input, and an integer output, and return another function g(x). The output of g(x) should be the same as f(x), except that when x is the same as the integer input, the output will be returned.

For example, given that we have a function sqrt which returns the square root of the argument. Using new_sqrt = exception_function(sqrt, 7, 2) we obtain new_sqrt, which behaves similarly to sqrt except for new_sqrt(7), where the value of 2 will be returned.

**Below is the answer template**

```
    from math import *

def exception_function(f, rejected_input, new_output):
    """Your code here"""
    pass

#################
#DO NOT REMOVE#
#################
new_sqrt = exception_function(sqrt, 7, 2)
```

**Test Cases:**

new_sqrt(9) -expected answer 3

new_sqrt(7) -expected answer 2

**Here is what im not sure about.**

1. How to control what f will return without changing f itself?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it!

```
def exception_function(f, rejected_input, new_output):
    def inner_function(x):
        if x==rejected_input:
            return new_output
        else:
            return f(x)
    return inner_function

new_sqrt = exception_function(sqrt, 7, 2)
```